# Limit the number of copies when printing in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, printing

Is it possible to limit the number of copies while printing in Silverlight 4? Perhaps the "number of copies" textbox in the Print dialog can be disabled somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to control the number of copies when printing from Silverlight. But at the following URL you'll find a way to achieve a "controlled" printing operation from Silverlight, that is: a way to execute a printing operation from Silverlight having the user not allowed to interact with the "Print" dialog box, that will be "auto-confirmed". In that way, the printing operation is forced to happen to the default printer only and in one (and only one) printed copy; in order to print further copies, the user will need to invoke again the print feature (and the application will be able to log properly the fact).

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/SilverlightSilentPrinting.aspx

Please note: it's a solution suitable only in specific scenarios (line of business applications, with control over the target client machine).